# Best Android Emulators for Mac for mobile site development?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion, bluestacks

Do you have any recommendations for Android emulators for Mac for mobile site development/testing? I hear Genymotion and Bluestacks are good but it also sounds like maybe they are specifically good for gaming sites/apps? What I have in mind is more of a news site.

Thanks in advance!
AE

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion is a very good emulator. Haven't used it for mobile site development, but I think it's one of (maybe THE) best